# Message app is extremely slow to open Big Sur

Tags: mac, messages, big-sur

Messages takes 5-10 seconds to open on Big Sur on my mac. When I click the Dock icon, the process starts, is "Not Responding" for 5-10 seconds and then opens normally. This occurs even when I am signed out of iMessage. I do not have iCloud iMessage backup enabled.

Any ideas?